# How to detect that the state value of useSelector is changed?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using React as the recommended function.

But even if I put the state value received from useSelector into useEffect's dep, useEffect doesn't execute as intended.

When submitLike is executed, the detailPost of the state value is updated, but useEffect is not executed except for the first time.

Can you suggest me a solution ?

Below is my tsx file and reducer

post.tsx(page)

```
const Post = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const detailPost = useSelector((store: RootState) => store.post.detailPost);
  const [post, setPost] = useState({ ...detailPost });

  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(
    { ...detailPost }.liker?.split(',').filter((v: string) => +v === me.id).length || 0,
  );

  const submitLike = () => {
    if (isLiked) dispatch(UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST({ userId: me.id, postId: detailPost.id }));
    else dispatch(LIKE_POST_REQUEST({ userId: me.id, postId: detailPost.id }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPostAPI(window.location.href.split('/')[4])
      .then((res) => {
        setPost(res.data);
        const currentLiked = res.data.liker?.split(',').filter((v: string) => +v === me.id).length || 0;
        setIsLiked(currentLiked);
        return currentLiked;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [detailPost]);

  return (
     ...
     post.User.nickname
     post.like
     ...
  );
};
export default Post;
```

post.ts(reducer)

```
const Post = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
     ...
    case LIKE_POST_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, likePostLoading: true, likePostDone: false, likePostError: null };
    case LIKE_POST_SUCCESS: {
      const posts: any[] = [...state.mainPosts];
      const post = posts.find((v) => v.id === action.data.postId);
      if (post.liker) post.liker += `,${action.data.userId}`;
      else post.liker = `${action.data.userId}`;
      post.like += 1;
      return { ...state, likePostLoading: false, likePostDone: true, likePostError: null, detailPost: post };
    }
    case UNLIKE_POST_SUCCESS: {
      const posts: any[] = [...state.mainPosts];
      const post = posts.find((v) => v.id === action.data.postId);
      const liker = post.liker.split(',');
      const idx = liker.find((v: string) => +v === action.data.userId);
      liker.splice(idx, 1);
      post.liker = liker.join('');
      post.like -= 1;
      return { ...state, unlikePostLoading: false, unlikePostDone: true, unlikePostError: null, detailPost: post };
    }
    default:
      return state;
     ...
  }
};

export default Post;
```

And when I click refresh, the post values ​​become undefined and an error occurs.
I also want to solve this problem with useEffect.

Comment: You shall create an `initialState`, create a slice using `createSlice` from `@reduxjs/toolkit`, and then use the `reducers` to change the state all in a separate file. Then, export the functions to be used in `useSelector` from this file and use this selector for the desired result.

Comment: Okay, you mean to splice the original copy of the shallow copy object and send it back? Thanks